# Kong using kubernetes ingress controller always returns 'failure to get a peer from the ring-balancer' when hit the Kong

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-ingress

I have installed Kong using Kubernetes-ingress-controller using these [steps](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/guides/getting-started.md). I am getting the following error when hit the Kong instance.

{"message":"failure to get a peer from the ring-balancer"}
[image]

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Kong could not connect to the upstream services, hence 503 error is returned.

Comment: Unsure why this is downvoted. The error implies that the backend/upstream service isn't deployed.
You can replicate this by following creating an ingress as per https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.3.x/guides/getting-started/#basic-proxy

but not setting up the backing echo server as per: https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.3.x/guides/getting-started/#set-up-an-echo-server

once you see the error, add the backend echo server and the issues goes away